# magic constant __CLASS__ used with get_class_vars() giving error

Tags: php, class, oop

Here i have a private variable called vars which is used to store all the variables inside a class.I am using `get_class_vars(__CLASS__)` to get all the variables.But it gives a parse error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\bal.php on line 5
```

if i removed the `get_class_vars(__CLASS__)` the code works.What might be causing the problem??

```
class lol{
   static private $message='i am shimantta !! ';
   private $msg='new';
   private $vars=get_class_vars( __CLASS__ );

   public function __get($var){

      echo $this->$var;
   }


}

$lol1=new lol();
$lol1->vars;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign 'dynamic' values to class property's in class definition. You can move them in the constructor. Also i think you want `$var` -> `$vars` and then it is an array so use `print_r()` or `var_dump()`, like this:

```
class lol {

    static private $message = "i am shimantta !! ";
    private $msg = "new";
    private $vars= "";

    public function __construct() {
        $this->vars = get_class_vars( __CLASS__);
    }

    public function __get($vars){
        print_r($this->$vars);
   }

}

$lol1 = new lol();
$lol1->vars;
```

For more information about property's see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

And a quote from there:

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is in this line:

```
private $vars=get_class_vars( __CLASS__ );
```

You cannot use a function when defining a class var, you should do that in the constructor:

```
class lol{
   private static $message='i am shimantta !! ';
   private $msg='new';
   private $vars;

   function __construct() {
      $this->vars=get_class_vars( __CLASS__ );
   }

   public function __get($var){

      echo $this->$var;
   }


}
```